# How do you find the average rate of change over an interval that is a compound inequality?

Tags: quadratics

Let $f(x)=0.7x^2$ and  $g(x)=2.8x^2$.

How do I find the average rate of change over $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ over the interval $[4,8]$?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. What have yout tried? Can you solve a simpler version of this problem?

Comment: Do you know what average rate of change over an interval is?